# Adding a static prefix on an incrementing number

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've created a column on my form named `trackingcode` and it increments every time you insert a new data.

Now I thought about adding a prefix and then the number so what I did was:

```
$Newtracking = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackingQuery)['REQ' . 'maxtrack'] + 1 ;
```

The `REQ` is the prefix that I wanted, but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Now other people are saying I could add the prefix on my view. I can't do that, I needed the prefix to be inserted on the database as well, the reason behind it is because I have a search bar that searches values from the database.

Here's the whole insert code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';


  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $trackingQuery = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT Max(trackingcode) as maxtrack FROM `request`");
        if( mysqli_num_rows($trackingQuery) > 0)
        {
        $Newtracking = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackingQuery)['maxtrack'] + 1 ;
        }
        else{
        $Newtracking = 1;
        }
        $query .= '
        INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
        VALUES("'.$Newtracking.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
        ';
  }
```

And here's my DB Schema:

[image: DB Schema]

Current `trackingcode` values on my DB:

[Current `trackingcode` values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi0QI.png)

```js
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $trackingcode = 'TS-' . substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
 

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   function generate ($value='',$inp=""){
       return $value.str_pad($inp,4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
 }
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
   if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
      $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
      $code = generate("REQ",$last_id);
    mysqli_query($connect,"update request set trackingcode='$code'  where reqnumber='$last_id'");
  }
```

[TB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2sr8.png)

[TB Duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlDxK.png)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxRNL.png)

[Add - Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrN44.png)

Comment: The only integer in your DB I can see is `reqnumber` which I assume is auto-incremented primary key. Is this what you are trying to increment?

Comment: @Dharman I purposely declared `trackingcode` as varchar so I could add a prefix to it, is that wrong? Btw I get incrementing values to my trackingcode as well. Please see my edit.

Comment: It is not wrong, if you know what you are doing and you have a strong reason for it. I would probably stay away from varchar if I knew I will need to store a number I will do mathematical operations on later. You can't increment a string. You need to find a logical way to split the string into prefix and number part, increase the number and store it again together.

Comment: It it possible if I could change the type to int and then add the `REQ` to it?

Comment: @Dharman Btw if I could use date (Y-m-d) instead of `REQ` and then the incrementing number, is that easier to do?

Comment: Again, I don't understand your question. If you can describe to me the difference between string, number and date, you should be able to store it correctly. Is REQ, just a constant used for displaying, or is it the part of the tracking number? Do you need to store REQ in the DB?

Comment: @Dharman Supposedly, `REQ` should be static and never change. I need to store the `REQ` in the DB as well. EG REQ1, REQ2, REQ3 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [str_pad()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp)

After insert get [last insert id](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp&ved=2ahUKEwikzN3zufXgAhVMiHAKHWCCBMEQFjALegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3TXR93ATSsBoz2UEIJiyKb&cshid=1552148032045).pass with generate function like this param

```
generate(prefix,last_insert_id);
```

Ex:`generate("REC",1);//REC0001`

```
function generate ($value='',$inp=""){
       return $value.str_pad($inp,4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}



  //Insert query

   $query = 'INSERT INTO request(req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) VALUES("'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); ';
     if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
      $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
      $code = generate("REQ",$last_id);
    mysqli_query($connect,"update request set trackingcode='$code'  where reqnumber='$last_id'");
    //exec code : update tablename set trackingcode='$code'  where tableprimary_id='$last_id'
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189758/discussion-on-answer-by-prasanth-adding-a-static-prefix-on-an-incrementing-numbe). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to include any relevant information from the conversation.