# Getting duplicates when I insert to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I have a form that works fine, but when I insert, it duplicates the values I sent minus the `trackingcode`. Here's a snip of the database after insertion:

[image: Duplicate]

I'm trying to figure out where it's coming from, positioning some elements outside the loop but I can't seem to fix it so I thought i'd ask.

Here's my insert code:

```js
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
 
 function generate ($value='',$inp=""){
       return $value.str_pad($inp, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
 }

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $query = '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
   if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
      $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
      $code = generate("REQ",$last_id);
    mysqli_query($connect,"update request set trackingcode='$code' where reqnumber='$last_id'");
  }
}
```

Whole Code:

```html
<?php
//insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';

 function generate ($value='',$inp=""){
       return $value.str_pad($inp, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $query = '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
   if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
      $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
      $code = generate("REQ",$last_id);
    mysqli_query($connect,"update request set trackingcode='$code'  where reqnumber='$last_id'");
    //exec code : update tablename set trackingcode='$code'  where tableprimary_id='$last_id'
 }
  }

$email_from = "PC Request";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "PC Request for $account_clean";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<tr><td>Good morning,</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Here are the specifications:</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="5">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Tracking Code</strong> </td><td style='color:blue;'>" . $trackingcode . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Start Date</strong> </td><td>" . $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Employee Name</strong> </td><td>" . $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Position</strong> </td><td>" . $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Account</strong> </td><td>" . $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Platform</strong> </td><td>" . $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Processor</strong> </td><td>" . $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>RAM</strong> </td><td>" . $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Monitor</strong> </td><td>" . $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Phone</strong> </td><td>" . $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Phone Type</strong> </td><td>" . $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Headset</strong> </td><td>" . $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Table</strong> </td><td>" . $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Chair</strong> </td><td>" . $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>For Approval</strong> </td><td><a href='teamspan.com/core/pcrequest/messages-admin.php'>Click Here!</a></td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
    
$to = "";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
//$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$message, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
//header('Location: index.php');

//-----------------------FOR IT TEAM-----------------------------//

$email_from = "PC Request";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "PC Request for $account_clean";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<tr><td>Good morning,</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Here are the specifications:</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="5">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Tracking Code</strong> </td><td style='color:blue;'>" . $trackingcode . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Start Date</strong> </td><td>" . $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Employee Name</strong> </td><td>" . $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Position</strong> </td><td>" . $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Account</strong> </td><td>" . $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Platform</strong> </td><td>" . $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Processor</strong> </td><td>" . $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>RAM</strong> </td><td>" . $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Monitor</strong> </td><td>" . $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Phone</strong> </td><td>" . $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Phone Type</strong> </td><td>" . $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Headset</strong> </td><td>" . $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Table</strong> </td><td>" . $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Chair</strong> </td><td>" . $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Update Work Status</strong> </td><td><a href='teamspan.com/core/pcrequest/messages-it.php'>Click Here!</a></td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
    
$to = "";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
//$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$message, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
//header('Location: index.php');

//-----------------------Without Admin-----------------------------//

$email_from = "PC Request";//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "PC Request for $account_clean";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<tr><td>Good morning,</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Here are the specifications:</td></tr>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= "<br>";
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="5">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Tracking Code</strong> </td><td style='color:blue;'>" . $trackingcode . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Requested by</strong> </td><td>" . $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Start Date</strong> </td><td>" . $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Employee Name</strong> </td><td>" . $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Position</strong> </td><td>" . $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Account</strong> </td><td>" . $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Platform</strong> </td><td>" . $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Processor</strong> </td><td>" . $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>RAM</strong> </td><td>" . $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Monitor</strong> </td><td>" . $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Phone</strong> </td><td>" . $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Phone Type</strong> </td><td>" . $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Headset</strong> </td><td>" . $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #FFFFFF;'><td><strong>Table</strong> </td><td>" . $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CDD9FF;'><td><strong>Chair</strong> </td><td>" . $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
    
$to = "";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
//$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$message, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
//header('Location: index.php');

}

 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'Successfuly Sent!';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'Error';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'All fields are required!';
 }
}
?>
```

```js
$('#save').click(function(){
  var trackingcode = [];
  var req_date = [];
  var reqname = [];
  var date = [];
  var empname = [];
  var position = [];
  var account = [];
  var platform = [];
  var processor = [];
  var ram = [];
  var monitor = [];
  var phone = [];
  var phonetype = [];
  var headset = [];
  var req_table = [];
  var req_chair = [];
  var approval = [];
  var status = [];
  $('.trackingcode').each(function(){
   trackingcode.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.req_date').each(function(){
   req_date.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.reqname').each(function(){
   reqname.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.date').each(function(){
   date.push($(this).find('input').val());
  });
  $('.empname').each(function(){
   empname.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.position').each(function(){
   position.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.account').each(function(){
   account.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.platform').each(function(){
   platform.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.processor').each(function(){
   processor.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.ram').each(function(){
   ram.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.monitor').each(function(){
   monitor.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.phone').each(function(){
   phone.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.phonetype').each(function(){
   phonetype.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.headset').each(function(){
   headset.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.req_table').each(function(){
   req_table.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.req_chair').each(function(){
   req_chair.push($(this).find('select').val());
  });
  $('.approval').each(function(){
   approval.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.status').each(function(){
   status.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert-message.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{trackingcode:trackingcode, req_date:req_date, reqname:reqname, date:date, empname:empname, position:position, account:account, platform:platform, processor:processor, ram:ram, monitor:monitor, phone:phone, phonetype:phonetype, headset:headset, req_table:req_table, req_chair:req_chair, approval:approval, status:status},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    window.location.reload()
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
```

Comment: What led you to believe the INSERT code alone is causing the duplicate entries?

Comment: Does the behavior change if `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);` is moved to a line before this line `if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){`?

Comment: @mario I just added the code from this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079158/adding-a-static-prefix-on-an-incrementing-number?noredirect=1#comment96905114_55079158` now I'm getting this problem.

Comment: @knot22 I still get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried using a `foreach` instead of a `for`?

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `$trackingcode`?

Comment: hmm, should I just change `for` to `foreach` literally?

Comment: Nope.  `foreach` is a different syntax.  Would there ever be more than 1 `$_POST["reqname"]` at a time?  I'm guessing the answer is yes based on how the existing loop is written but just want to double check.

Comment: @knot22 Yep. Actually I just added this code from here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079158/adding-a-static-prefix-on-an-incrementing-number?noredirect=1#comment96905114_55079158` then I got the problem

Comment: The screen shot shows the first row has the trackingcode column populated while the second one does not.  Two questions: Where is the line that sets `$trackingcode` equal to a value?  If you delete those test rows from the database and try send one `$_POST["reqname"]` in, are 2 rows still inserted?  Since there is no column in the table that shows a Created date with timestamp we can't tell if they were from 2 separate test insertions performed at different times or if the code caused 2 insertions when it ran.

Comment: @knot22 forgot to mention I'm using a dynamic form where users can add input fields.

Comment: So long as `$trackingcode` is unaffected by the input fields being dynamic, I think that's fine.  The code will run after the Submit button is clicked.

Comment: Good call by @dWinder to remove the period from `$query .= `.  I would've expected that to resolve this issue.  But sounds like not.  When you disable the code that adds the prefix on an incremented number, does the insertion go back to 1 row?

Comment: Yup, I had the problem right after I added the prefix.

Comment: Just to verify that is indeed the source of the problem, I would recommend commenting out all the code associated with that and run a test again.

Comment: @knot22 Yup, I've already done that and indeed it was the source of the problem, I think it's the positioning inside the loop but I'm not sure

Comment: Interesting.  In the `INSERT` statement, I see `trackingcode` is the first column.  I don't think there would be a reason to have that in the `INSERT` statement since the `UPDATE` is handling population of that column.  Removing that is unlikely to fix the double insert problem but it should probably be taken out to keep the code clean.  It would have to be taken out of the `INSERT` and the `VALUES` associated with that `INSERT`.  I will think some more about the prefix.

Comment: @knot22 Actually, on my previous post (the link I sent), the answer doesn't have `trackingcode` on the insert statement. But I'm getting errors when I hit send, so I added `trackingcode` to the insert statement again.

Comment: What are the errors are being generated when `trackingcode` is removed?

Comment: Can you verify the array has different values before the loop? Can it be that page is been called twice?

Comment: @knot22 It just says error, I added the whole code so you'll see the whole picture. I have to add the `trackingcode` to the query for the insert to work.

Comment: Yes, thje array should have different values before the loop @dWinder

Comment: Maybe the column is defined as NOT NULL in the table which would cause an error if `trackingcode` was omitted from the `INSERT`.  In the `VALUES` you could insert an empty string rather than `$trackingcode` for that first column.  I don't see `$trackingcode` declared and initialized before the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @knot22 That makes sense, so I tried changing `trackingcode` to null and it worked but I'm still getting the duplicate.

Comment: Does the double insert behavior change if this `"update request set trackingcode='$code'` is changed to `"update request set trackingcode='$last_id'`?

Comment: @knot22 It's still the same, I have a question tho, it it correct to move `function generate` outside `for`?

Comment: It appears to be outside of the `for` loop already and that is fine.

Comment: Since the result is the same on the last test (changing `$code` to `$last_id` in `UPDATE`) that rules out the `function generate` from being the problem.

Comment: If a value is hardcoded into `$last_id`, rather than calling `mysqli_insert_id`, what happens?

Comment: @knot22 I added the JS from my index, if that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Notice you define (in your updated code):

```
$query .= 'INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_...
```

When using `.` before the `=` it concat the string to existing one. So basically you add more and more INSERT to your query. Remove the `.`

Comment: I've actually thought about it, so I removed `.` but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Please update the code you added (and if you can indent it that would be helpful) - it is still there... and remember: SQL injection...