# how to add string to the random generated number using php?

Tags: php

In my php code, while inserting new record, invoice number should be 0001. Here I want to add characters/a word(for example 'optical') and it should be like `optical0001`. How can I add this before the number?

```
$query          = "select * from cust_report_invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1";
    $result         = $link->query($query);
    $row            = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $invoiceNo      = $row['invoiceNo'];
    $prefix = 'Baopt_'; 
    $getinvoiceNo   = $prefix . str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$sql            = "INSERT INTO cust_report_invoices (invoiceNo,invoiceDate)
VALUES ('$getinvoiceNo', '$getinvoiceDate'            )";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a static prefix on an incrementing number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079158/adding-a-static-prefix-on-an-incrementing-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_pad` return string ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)). So just concat with `.`:

```
$prefix = 'optical';
$invoice   = $prefix . str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Edit**

When adding new element you need to cut the prefix out - you can use this:

```
$prefix = 'Baopt_';
$invoiceNo = $row['invoiceNo']; 
if (substr($invoiceNo, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) // if already has prefix
    $invoiceNo = substr($invoiceNo, strlen($prefix)); // remove it
$getinvoiceNo   = $prefix . str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: invoiceno is unique key in database.Here am facing issue ie when first time am inserting like Baopt_001.It is not adding Baopt_002 on the second time.Its still adding Baopt_001 on the second insertion and so it is showing error called duplicate entry

Comment: @becool What is the code you use to insert data to DB? this seem new issue and not related to the string concatenation - Did you open new question about it?

Comment: there is no issues in insert query.In this code invoice number is not adding thats my issue

Comment: Does "invoiceNo" field in the DB is int or string?

Comment: when i removed "Baopt_ ".it will insert like 001 ,002 etc...I am facing issue when "Baopt_ "added

Comment: varchar(20) (invoice no).It will insert at first time like Baopt_001.

Comment: This happens because in the second time the `$invoiceNo` is "Baopt_001" so adding it 1 does nothing

Comment: yes u r right sir.Is there any other way to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

When working in PHP you can use the `.` as concatenation-operator. I see that you use the function [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) that returns as string.

So you can just concat the prefix with the invoice number like this.

```
$prefix = 'optical';
$invoice   = $prefix . str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`$prefix` can be anything you want.

When `invoice = 0001` this example will return `optical0001`

Answer (score 0):

Just `"Opticals".$getinvoiceNo`
Dot is concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, you want to prepend "optical" to $getinvoiceNo?

If yes then it is simple,

`invoiceId = "optical$getinvoiceNo"`